# Seeking help in simplifying a TikZ Tonnetz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've created a *Tonnetz*, a type of musical network in Ti*k*Z:

```
%LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5,yscale=2.5]
\footnotesize

\begin{scope}
\newcommand*\columns{7}
\newcommand*\rows{2}
\clip(0,0.5) rectangle (\columns,\rows);
\foreach \x in {0,0.5,1,...,\columns}
\foreach \y in {0,0.5,1,...,\rows}
\foreach \z in {-1.5,-0.5,...,\columns} 
{
    \draw (0,\y) -- (\columns,\y);
    \draw (\z,\rows) -- (\z+2,0);
    \draw (\z,0) -- (\z+2,\rows);
}
\end{scope}

\draw[fill=gray!50] (3.5,1) -- (4.5,1) -- (4,1.5) -- cycle;
\foreach \toprow/\topx in {E/0.5,B/1.5,F$\sharp$/2.5,C$\sharp$/3.5,G$\sharp$/4.5,D$\sharp$/5.5,A$\sharp$/6.5}
\foreach \secondrow/\secondx in {C/0,G/1,D/2,A/3,E/4,B/5,F$\sharp$/6,C$\sharp$/7}
\foreach \thirdrow/\thirdx in {E$\flat$/0.5,B$\flat$/1.5,F/2.5,C/3.5,G/4.5,D/5.5,A/6.5}
\foreach \fourthrow/\fourthx in {C$\flat$/0,G$\flat$/1,D$\flat$/2,A$\flat$/3,E$\flat$/4,B$\flat$/5,F/6,C/7}
%\foreach \bottomrow/\bottomx in {E$\flat\flat$/0.5,B$\flat\flat$/1.5,F$\flat$/2.5,C$\flat$/3.5,G$\flat$/4.5,D$\flat$/5.5,A$\flat$/6.5}
{
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.75cm,fill=white] at (\topx,2) {\toprow};
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.75cm,fill=white] at (\secondx,1.5) {\secondrow};
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.75cm,fill=white] at (\thirdx,1) {\strut \thirdrow};
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.75cm,fill=white] at (\fourthx,0.5) {\strut \fourthrow};
%\node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.75cm,fill=white] at (\bottomx,0) {\strut \bottomrow};
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As written, with the two lines commented out, the output is correct. However, it is *very* slow to compile. (Even Inkscape and PDF readers are slow to open the file!) And when I uncomment those two lines to create the bottom row, nothing ever results; sometimes I get the "TeX capacity exceeded" error, but other times it goes on compiling so long that I just give up.

Ideally I will have four or five diagrams like this in this chapter (itself part of a much larger book), so these compile times aren't realistic. Is there any way to simplify this diagram to help it compile faster?

Comment: Why are you nesting the loops? Aren't you just adding the same nodes multiple times?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, and if you mean the note names themselves, they are a string of the same note names. But each row will begin at a different place along that string, and I didn't know how to make that work.

Comment: Well, both the grid lines and the node names. Take for example the horizontal lines. Each horizontal line is drawn 140 times I think, because it is at the innermost level of three nested loops. (There are 14 iterations of the outermost loop, and 10 iterations in the innermost loop.) A single `\foreach \y in {0,0.5,1,...\rows} \draw (0,\y) -- (\columns,\y);` would do for the horizontal lines.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Oh wow, so I do; I can't believe I didn't catch that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned previously, your problem is that you're doing the same thing *many* times, because you're nesting the loops. Take the loops drawing the grid. The drawing instructions in the innermost loop (over `\z`) is repeated for each iteration of that loop. But the *entire loop* is again repeated for each iteration of the second loop (over `\y`). And that loop is repeated for each iteration of the outermost loop (over `\x`). As a result, because there are 10 steps in the x-loop and 14 steps in the z-loop, you're drawing every horizontal line 140 times.

The same thing happens for the nodes. Each consecutive loop is repeated for every iteration of the loop it's placed within, so when you get five levels deep, with 7 or 8 iterations in each level, you end up drawing each node over 3000 times.

For the grid, you could do this:

```
\begin{scope}
\newcommand*\columns{7}
\newcommand*\rows{2}
\clip(0,-\pgflinewidth) rectangle (\columns,\rows);
\foreach \y in {0,0.5,1,...,\rows} 
  \draw (0,\y) -- (\columns,\y);

%the previous loop has ended, start a new:
\foreach \z in {-1.5,-0.5,...,\columns} 
{
    \draw (\z,\rows) -- (\z+2,0);
    \draw (\z,0) -- (\z+2,\rows);
}
\end{scope}
```

The horizontal lines are drawn in one loop, the diagonal lines in a separate loop.

For the nodes you can do the same thing, have one loop for each line:

```
\foreach \toprow [count=\topx] in {E,B,F$\sharp$,C$\sharp$,G$\sharp$,D$\sharp$,A$\sharp$}
   \node[note] at (\topx-0.5,2) {\toprow};

\foreach \secondrow [count=\secondx from 0] in {C,G,D,A,E,B,F$\sharp$,C$\sharp$}
   \node[note] at (\secondx,1.5) {\secondrow};

\foreach \thirdrow[count=\thirdx] in {E$\flat$,B$\flat$,F,C,G,D,A}
   \node[note] at (\thirdx-0.5,1) {\strut \thirdrow};
   
\foreach \fourthrow[count=\fourthx from 0] in {C$\flat$,G$\flat$,D$\flat$,A$\flat$,E$\flat$,B$\flat$,F,C}
  \node[note] at (\fourthx,0.5) {\strut \fourthrow};

\foreach \bottomrow[count=\bottomx] in {E$\flat\flat$,B$\flat\flat$,F$\flat$,C$\flat$,G$\flat$,D$\flat$,A$\flat$}
  \node[note] at (\bottomx-0.5,0) {\strut \bottomrow};
```

I.e. instead of having `foreach x (foreach y (foreach z <do stuff x y and z> ) )`, you have `foreach x <do stuff x>`, then `foreach y <do stuff y>` etc.

Above I made use of the `count` feature of `\foreach`, that way you don't have to fiddle around with the `a/b` syntax. You could also iterate over a list of lists:

```
\foreach  \notelist [count=\row from 0] in {
  {E$\flat\flat$,B$\flat\flat$,F$\flat$,C$\flat$,G$\flat$,D$\flat$,A$\flat$},
  {C$\flat$,G$\flat$,D$\flat$,A$\flat$,E$\flat$,B$\flat$,F,C},
  {E$\flat$,B$\flat$,F,C,G,D,A},
  {C,G,D,A,E,B,F$\sharp$,C$\sharp$},
  {E,B,F$\sharp$,C$\sharp$,G$\sharp$,D$\sharp$,A$\sharp$}}
  \foreach \note [count=\column from 0,evaluate={\colX=\column+0.5-mod(\row,2)/2;}] in \notelist
     \node [note] at (\colX,\row*0.5) {\strut \note};
```

There are some simple calculations to get the coordinates correct.

Complete code, containing both variants for the nodes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  xscale=1.5,yscale=2.5981,
  note/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=0.75cm,fill=white},
  every node/.append style={font=\footnotesize}
  ]
%\footnotesize

\begin{scope}
\newcommand*\columns{7}
\newcommand*\rows{2}
\clip(0,-\pgflinewidth) rectangle (\columns,\rows);
\foreach \y in {0,0.5,1,...,\rows} 
  \draw (0,\y) -- (\columns,\y);
\foreach \z in {-1.5,-0.5,...,\columns} 
{
    \draw (\z,\rows) -- (\z+2,0);
    \draw (\z,0) -- (\z+2,\rows);
}
\end{scope}

\draw[fill=gray!50] (3.5,1) -- (4.5,1) -- (4,1.5) -- cycle;
%\foreach \toprow [count=\topx] in {E,B,F$\sharp$,C$\sharp$,G$\sharp$,D$\sharp$,A$\sharp$}
%   \node[note] at (\topx-0.5,2) {\toprow};
%
%\foreach \secondrow [count=\secondx from 0] in {C,G,D,A,E,B,F$\sharp$,C$\sharp$}
%   \node[note] at (\secondx,1.5) {\secondrow};
%
%\foreach \thirdrow[count=\thirdx] in {E$\flat$,B$\flat$,F,C,G,D,A}
%   \node[note] at (\thirdx-0.5,1) {\strut \thirdrow};
%   
%\foreach \fourthrow[count=\fourthx from 0] in {C$\flat$,G$\flat$,D$\flat$,A$\flat$,E$\flat$,B$\flat$,F,C}
%  \node[note] at (\fourthx,0.5) {\strut \fourthrow};
%
%\foreach \bottomrow[count=\bottomx] in {E$\flat\flat$,B$\flat\flat$,F$\flat$,C$\flat$,G$\flat$,D$\flat$,A$\flat$}
%  \node[note] at (\bottomx-0.5,0) {\strut \bottomrow};


\foreach [count=\row from 0] \notelist in {
  {E$\flat\flat$,B$\flat\flat$,F$\flat$,C$\flat$,G$\flat$,D$\flat$,A$\flat$},
  {C$\flat$,G$\flat$,D$\flat$,A$\flat$,E$\flat$,B$\flat$,F,C},
  {E$\flat$,B$\flat$,F,C,G,D,A},
  {C,G,D,A,E,B,F$\sharp$,C$\sharp$},
  {E,B,F$\sharp$,C$\sharp$,G$\sharp$,D$\sharp$,A$\sharp$}}
  \foreach \note [count=\column from 0,evaluate={\colX=\column+0.5-mod(\row,2)/2;}] in \notelist
     \node [note] at (\colX,\row*0.5) {\strut \note};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you not only for the diagnosis and the answer, but the clear explanations along the way. I'm not a programmer, so this was immensely helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of nesting loops unnecessarily, I make a test in a single loop on the number of nodes to display (7; 8; 7 and 8 per line).

[image: screenshot]

```
%LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5,yscale=2.5981]
\footnotesize

\begin{scope}
\newcommand*\columns{7}
\newcommand*\rows{2}
\clip(0,0.5) rectangle (\columns,\rows);
 %\foreach \x in {0,0.5,1,...,\columns}
\foreach \y in {0,0.5,1,...,\rows}
\foreach \z in {-1.5,-0.5,...,\columns} 
{
    \draw (0,\y) -- (\columns,\y);
    \draw (\z,\rows) -- (\z+2,0);
    \draw (\z,0) -- (\z+2,\rows);
}
\end{scope}

\draw[fill=gray!50] (3.5,1) -- (4.5,1) -- (4,1.5) -- cycle;
\foreach \row/\x [count=\n]in {E/0.5,B/1.5,F$\sharp$/2.5,C$\sharp$/3.5,G$\sharp$/4.5,D$\sharp$/5.5,A$\sharp$/6.5,C/0,G/1,D/2,A/3,E/4,B/5,F$\sharp$/6,C$\sharp$/7,E$\flat$/0.5,B$\flat$/1.5,F/2.5,C/3.5,G/4.5,D/5.5,A/6.5,C$\flat$/0,G$\flat$/1,D$\flat$/2,A$\flat$/3,E$\flat$/4,B$\flat$/5,F/6,C/7}
%\foreach \bottomrow/\bottomx in {E$\flat\flat$/0.5,B$\flat\flat$/1.5,F$\flat$/2.5,C$\flat$/3.5,G$\flat$/4.5,D$\flat$/5.5,A$\flat$/6.5}
{
\ifnum \n < 8
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.75cm,fill=white] at (\x,2) {\row};
\else 
    \ifnum \n <16
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.75cm,fill=white] at (\x,1.5) {\row};
    \else   
        \ifnum \n <23    
        \node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.75cm,fill=white] at (\x,1) {\strut \row};
        \else 
        \node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.75cm,fill=white] at (\x,0.5) {\strut \row};
        \fi
    \fi
\fi
%\node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.75cm,fill=white] at (\bottomx,0) {\strut \bottomrow};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
```